# Can I use co-dependent features in a Random Forest?

Tags: random-forest, entropy

Let's say my features for a random forest are: `x,y,z,x/y,x/z,y/z`. These are obviously co-dependent. Now, when training a Random Forest (using `sklearn` for example), the minimization of the entropy assumes that the features are independent - as this makes the entropy derivation much simpler. Still, these models seems to work - am I missing something?

Comment: This looks like [feature engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_engineering) to me.

Comment: No, my question comes one step after that - once I have my features and I understand they are correlated - can I use them?

Comment: Part of the "question behind the question" is "how do you measure the 'done' of that first step".  Why is "x" a feature and "x/y" not one?  What makes "x/y" not one?  Personally, I would say that if the random forest, with proper cross-validation gets better fit with "x/y" than without, then "x/y" counts as an informative input.  The wikipedia says "any attribute can be a feature as long as it is useful to the model".  What if they aren't wrong?  That would suggest that if "x/y" is useful to the model, then it comprises a feature.

Comment: think of `x` and `x/y` as a simplified example - assume I have two variables, `x` and `f`, where `f` might be a function of `x` and there's no way of knowing. Now - will the random forest estimators be correct?

Comment: I get that.  When you say "correct" do you mean "accuracy", "generalization", or un-brittle (aka anti-fragile)?

Comment: All of the above (though not sure what anti-fragile means :) )

Comment: here you go.  [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antifragility)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the discussion above with EngrStudent and others off this site, the conclusion is that we can use co-dependent features, because:

- Not all trees use entropy calculations
- Even those who do, do not necessarily derive it

So it seems as it makes sense, and even improves classification due to better feature engineering.